# How we can enable maintenance mode of your Magento website?

Tags: magento-1.8

How we can enable maintenance mode of your Magento website

Answer (score 1):

Create **maintenance.flag** empty file in Magento root directory. The run frontend. You will see maintenance page.

To exclude your IP in maintenance, Open **index.php** in root and above line 57 add (remembering to edit the ‘allowed’ array to contain the IP’s you want to be able to access the site);

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'); // these are the IP's that are allowed to view the site.
```

then change the line

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
```

to

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
```

Now you can access the site, while others see maintenance mode.

Comment: Just an idea ... take allowed IPs from config settings `dev/restrict/allow_ips` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an empty file with filename as `maintenance.flag` and upload it to the magento root folder. By now your magento website is under maintenance mode.

And remove `maintenance.flag` file to remove your website from the maintenance mode.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answers, you can edit the displayed maintenance message in `errors/default/503.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides a simple solution to enable maintenance mode. To enable maintenance mode, just add an empty file called **`maintenance.flag`** to magento's root folder.

Although above feature is great, but by default it loads Magento's default layout. To edit it, you would need to make changes in **`errors/default/503.phtml`** file and appropriate css file(s).

If you want an easy and more configurable solution, then there are many extensions available which provide you more controls and easy management of design. Few of those extensions are listed below:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/maintenance-mode-4.html **(Free)**

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/maintenance-mode-2.html **(Paid)**

Some great features provided by these extensions are listed below:

- Admin can choose which static block to show on this page.
- Selected IPs can also be provided that can still access the storefront.
- Admin user can get full access front end if configured.
- There's an option to show a countdown timer and expected up date/time.
- Admin user can get full access front end if configured.

I hope, my answer is clear enough to understand. Please let me know if you have any query.